# Does 'Jabbing Style' transfer its bonus over rounds?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, monk, unchained

I recently leveled my *Unchained Monk* to level 7, which now allows me to take [Jabbing Style](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/feats.html#jabbing-style).

Its description reads:

> When you hit a target with an unarmed strike and you have hit that target with an unarmed strike previously that round, you deal an extra 1d6 points of damage to that target.

Does this bonus really only apply to the same **round**? Or, in other words, which is correct:

*(Assuming all attacks on the same target)*

**Option 1**

- **Round 1**
- Hit 1: No bonus
- Hit 2: +1d6
- Hit 3: +1d6
- **Round 2**
- Hit 1: No bonus
- Hit 2: +1d6
- Hit 3: +1d6

**Option 2**

- **Round 1**
- Hit 1: No bonus
- Hit 2: +1d6
- Hit 3: +1d6
- **Round 2**
- Hit 1: +1d6
- Hit 2: +1d6
- Hit 3: +1d6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's option 1. The wording unambiguously states that it applies only to hits to that target made that round, so the first hit each round against a target would lack the bonus. The benefit of this feat can be useful for full attacks and opportunity attacks, but it's not a permanent (or even encounter-long) +1d6 to all hits against a given target after the first like option 2 seems to think.

Comment: I was suspecting this already, but was unsure about the wording. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Note that if you miss your target on the first hit you don't get the bonus for the second.